# How do I link to my careers.stackoverflow.com profile?

Tags: support, jobs

I thought I used to be able to view my profile as an employer would see it and use that URL to link people to my profile.

I can't seem to find that anymore, how can I get a nice sharable link to my careers.stackoverflow.com profile?

Comment: When did StackOverflow REMOVE this feature and the "jobs" tab?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You find it under the `privacy settings` area:

[image: Privacy settings link]

Once there it is prominently displayed for easy copying:

[image: Public view URL]

Comment: Thanks, just adding a link for others to see what it actually looks like.
https://stackoverflow.com/cv/zopatista

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this has changed recently and careers.stackoverflow.com is only for companies/people seeking talent, not job seekers.

**Looks like the way to do this now is via the 'jobs' tab on stackoverflow.com, click 'edit CV':**

---

[image: enter image descriptidon here]

---

**Then click 'settings':**

---

[image]

---

### **And lastly click 'Make Public':**

[image]

---

Then you will be able to access your profile with the following pattern => https://stackoverflow.com/cv/ElijahLynn

Quick link: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/privacy/328579 (your ID) and click "Make public".

Comment: these links are broken.  Where did your CV go?

Comment: StackOverflow Careers was recently discontinued on March 31st, 2022. 

See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story.